# How to show Checkmark in tableview swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I have to show check mark before i selected for some array values, i have to show the checkmark for array value 1 and none for 0.How to do that..check the code below:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = AllItems[indexPath.row] as? String
    for dict1  in selectedItems
    {
         if Intvalues == dict1 as? NSObject  {
           // I have to show CheckMark
}
          else if ZeroIntvalues == dict1 as? NSObject
         {
            // I don’t need to show CheckMark



        }
    }
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    return cell
}
```

Comment: AllItems = ["BMW","Audi", "Volkswagen"] selectedItems = [“1”,”0”,”1”] Intvalues =1 ZeroIntvalues=0

Comment: You certainly don't want a for loop in cellForRowAtIndexPath. You should use the indexPath to index into the array

Comment: Thank you for correcting my mistakes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of reason @Paulw11 said, your code is wrong. Each tableViewCell is displayed checkmark because the last object of `for` loop is always `1`.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = AllItems[indexPath.row] as? String
        if Intvalues == AllItems[indexPath.row] as? Int  {
           // I have to show CheckMark
          cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
         } else {
          cell.accessoryType = .None
         }
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting my mistakes...It's working now.

Comment: BTW textLabel property is [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623210-textlabel)

Answer (score 1):

Tableview cell has accessory type ,
Use this in tableviewCellForRowAtIndexPath

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

Comment: AllItems  = ["BMW","Audi", "Volkswagen"]
selectedItems = [“1”,”0”,”1”]
Intvalues =1
ZeroIntvalues=0....... I tried  this cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; but it display check mark for all cell

Comment: If the question was asked in Swift you should really provide the answer in Swift as well...

Answer (score 1):

you show check mark as below .

```
  cell.accessoryType = .None
if Intvalues == dict1 as? NSObject  {
     // I have to show CheckMark
     cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
}
```

Comment: I tried that...But it display checkmark for all cell,If i change to None its' not display check mark....I want to show particular array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that I have used in my app,

If you are using webservice, then after calling a webservice
implement this logic:

this code in webservice calling section:

```
for i in 0..<arrNL.count {
   let dict = arrNL[i].mutableCopy() as! NSMutableDictionary
   dict.setObject("0", forKey: "isChecked")
   self.arrNotificationList.addObject(dict)
}
// Here 0 indicates that initially all are uncheck.
```

Now manage condition in CellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
let dict = arrNotificationList[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
if(dict["isChecked"] as! String == "0") { // Unchecked
   cell.btn_CheckUnCheck.setImage(UIImage(named: "uncheck"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
} else { // Checked
   cell.btn_CheckUnCheck.setImage(UIImage(named: "check"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
// in this condition you can manage check uncheck status
```

Now code for a button from which we can check or uncheck it

```
let dict = arrNotificationList[indexValue] as! NSMutableDictionary
if(dict["isChecked"] as! String == "1") {
   dict.setObject("0", forKey: "isChecked")
} else {
   dict.setObject("1", forKey: "isChecked")
}
arrNotificationList.replaceObjectAtIndex(indexValue, withObject: dict)
tblView.reloadData()
```