# The best way to use checkbox - IOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, checkbox

I am going to work on a project that will use a lot of checkboxes. I found a solution like below, but I know this not right way.

```
 @IBAction func btn_box(sender: UIButton) {
    if (btn_box.selected == true)
    {
        btn_box.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "box"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            btn_box.selected = false;
    }
    else
    {
        btn_box.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "checkBox"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        btn_box.selected = true;
    }
}
```

So, can anyone show me the right way of having more than 20 checkboxes in my project?

I will use checkboxes in forms and for settings purpose.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Tableview cell for it?

Comment: No i use in form and in settings purpose

Comment: Please follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40782238/how-to-show-checkmark-in-tableview-swift/40782436#40782436

Comment: So, Do you want to create 20 checkboxes statically?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are lots of [Checkbox control](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=checkbox) or you do it by this simple way:

**For Storyboard:**

1. Set your button's selected image:

   [image]
2. Set your button's default image:

   [image]

**For Programmatically:**

```
btn_box.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "box"), for: .normal)
btn_box.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "checkBox"), for: .selected)
```

And in button action:

```
@IBAction func btn_box(sender: UIButton) { 
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of checking each and every button, just use a generic way to handle this. Set all your button to the same IBAction method and implement that like:

```
@IBAction func btn_box(sender: UIButton)
{
    // Instead of specifying each button we are just using the sender (button that invoked) the method
    if (sender.selected == true)
    {
        sender.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "box"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        sender.selected = false;
    }
    else
    {
        sender.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "checkBox"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        sender.selected = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the approach below which will most helpful:
In your `StoryBoard` or `ViewDidLoad` assign the image for `UIButton`:

```
checkBoxButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "box"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
checkBoxButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "checkBox"), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
```

After this in your `@IBAction` Method just implement the following code:

```
@IBAction func btn_box(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.selected = !sender.selected
}
```

This will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "uncheckImage"), for: UIControlState.normal)
btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkImage"), for: UIControlState.selected)

@IBAction func btn_box(sender: UIButton) {

     if btn.isSelected == true {

          btn.isSelected = false
     }
     else {

          btn.isSelected = true
     }
}
```

Comment: Or maybe just button.isSelected = !button.isSelected

Answer (score 0):

It gives me a great pleasure to inform you all that solve above issue

## Resolving Issue Is

1. CheckBox Functionality
2. RadioButton Functionality
3. ReuseCell(tableView.dequeueReusableCell)//Also solve selected cell position issue.

## Tested Code

- Swift 5
- iOS 12.2

## Here is my code

```
import UIKit

class countrySelection:UITableViewCell{
     @IBOutlet weak var imgFlag: UIImageView!
     @IBOutlet weak var lblCountryName: UILabel!
     @IBOutlet weak var btnSelection: UIButton!
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var listingDict=[[String:String]]()

    var radioOption:Int?// Only used :: if u are 2. RadioButton Functionality implement

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        tableView.dataSource=self
        tableView.delegate=self
    
        fillCountryData()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func fillCountryData(){
        self.fillJsonData(imgName: "india_flag", countryName: "India")
        self.fillJsonData(imgName: "pakistan_flag", countryName: "Pakistan")
        self.fillJsonData(imgName: "israel_flag", countryName: "Israel")
        self.fillJsonData(imgName: "albania_flag", countryName: "Albania")
        self.fillJsonData(imgName: "america_flag", countryName: "America")
        self.fillJsonData(imgName: "belize_flag", countryName: "Belize")
        self.fillJsonData(imgName: "brunei_flag", countryName: "Brunei")
        self.fillJsonData(imgName: "comoros_flag", countryName: "Comoros")
        self.fillJsonData(imgName: "congo_flag", countryName: "Congo")
        self.fillJsonData(imgName: "ecuador_flag", countryName: "Ecuador")
        self.fillJsonData(imgName: "haiti_flag", countryName: "Haiti")
        self.fillJsonData(imgName: "jamaica_flag", countryName: "Jamaica")
        self.fillJsonData(imgName: "kenya_flag", countryName: "Kenya")
        self.fillJsonData(imgName: "mali_flag", countryName: "Mali")
    
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func fillJsonData(imgName:String,countryName:String){
        var dictData=[String:String]()
        dictData["img"]=imgName
        dictData["country"]=countryName
        dictData["check"]="false"
        listingDict.append(dictData)
    }

}

extension ViewController:UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return listingDict.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "countrySelection") as! countrySelection
        let dictVal=listingDict[indexPath.row]
        cell.lblCountryName.text=dictVal["country"]
        cell.imgFlag.image=UIImage(named:dictVal["img"]!)
    
        /*//Check Box Functionality
        if dictVal["check"] == "false"{
            cell.btnSelection.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox_UnSelect"), for: .normal)
        } else{
            cell.btnSelection.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox_Select"), for: .normal)
        }*/
    
        //RadioButton Functionality
        if radioOption==indexPath.row{
            listingDict[indexPath.row]["check"]="true"
            cell.btnSelection.setImage(UIImage(named: "radioButton_Select"), for: .normal)
        } else{
            listingDict[indexPath.row]["check"]="false"
            cell.btnSelection.setImage(UIImage(named: "radioButton_UnSelect"), for: .normal)
        }
    
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        /*//CheckBox Functionality
        if listingDict[indexPath.row]["check"]=="true"{
            listingDict[indexPath.row]["check"]="false"
        } else{
            listingDict[indexPath.row]["check"]="true"
        }*/
        //RadioButton Functionality
        print("RadioButton",listingDict)
        if listingDict[indexPath.row]["check"]=="true"{
            radioOption=nil
        } else{
            radioOption=indexPath.row
        }
    
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```