# how to get value button checkbox

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a button for checkbox, and I've set an action in code:

```
- (IBAction)check1:(id)sender {
if (!chaked) {
    [check1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     NSLog(@"Unchecked");
    chaked = YES;
} else if (chaked) {
    [check1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSLog(@"checked");
    chaked = NO;
}
```

how do I get the results of the log?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41344895/the-best-way-to-use-checkbox-ios-swift/41345216#41345216

Comment: Where you want result?

Comment: what result? please elaborate clearly

Comment: NSlog(@"%d", chaked); try this

Comment: your question is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UIButton` instead of `id`. It will be easier in case you are sure that this action will only be called by `UIButton` objects.

Anyway, `UIButton` stores its value in the `selected` property, which can be retrieved with the `isSelected` getter. However, if you made your checkbox with an `IUButton`, you will probably also need to make it selected/unselected programatically with `[sender setSelected:![sender isSelected]];`

**UPDATE:** Just noticed that you want to change the image if it's selected or not. Instead, call that in your viewDidLoad:

```
[check1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[check1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And here is your IBAction:

```
- (IBAction)check1:(UIButton*)sender 
{
    [sender setSelected:![sender isSelected]];

    if (sender.isSelected == false) {
        NSLog(@"Unchecked");
    } 
    else {
        NSLog(@"checked");
    }
}
```